# Jquery Datepicker set only 3 dates from before and after the corrsponding date

Tags: jquery, datepicker, maxdate, mindate

I have used two jquery datepickers. 
In first date picker I choose the date like "18-MAR-2012" and The next date picker should show only the date from 15-MAR-2012 to 21-MAR-2012.
It should add only 3 days from before and after the particular date("18-MAR-2012")
How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4495603/1013082 Check this solution out. You'll need to tweak it, of course, but it should give you a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to range datepicker. I found solution and may be this wud help you. The working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hS6aX/1/)(Stylings missing in fiddle). Here I'm setting the limit for next date picker at "onSelect" function of first datepicker.

```
var d;var tempdate; var tempdate1; var da; var da1;
$('#nam1').datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: 'd/m/yy',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    showAnim: 'slideDown',
    duration: 0,
    onSelect: function(dateStr) {
        d = $.datepicker.parseDate('d/m/yy', dateStr); //Get selected date
        tempdate = new Date(d);
        tempdate1 = new Date(d);
        tempdate.setDate(tempdate.getDate() - 3);    //Subtracted 3 days
        tempdate1.setDate(tempdate1.getDate() + 3);  // added 3 days 
        da = new Date(tempdate);
        da1 = new Date(tempdate1);
    }
});

$('#nam2').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'd/m/yy',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    showAnim: 'slideDown',
    duration: 0,
    beforeShow: function(input)
        {
            //setting min and max date for second datepicker
            if(da1 != undefined) return { minDate: da, maxDate: da1 }; 
        }
});​
```

There wud be even better way to handle date variable. Try it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var threeDays = 259200000;
            $('#datepicker2').datepicker("option", "minDate", new Date(Date.parse(dateText)-threeDays));
            $('#datepicker2').datepicker("option", "maxDate", new Date(Date.parse(dateText)+threeDays));
            $('#datepicker2').datepicker("setDate", dateText);
        }
    });
    $('#datepicker2').datepicker();
});
```

...259200000 is 3 days in micro-seconds.
every time you select a date in the first datepicker, it restricts the range in the 2. one.
Unfortunately, if i leave out `$('#datepicker2').datepicker("setDate", dateText);`, the date in the second datepicker is set to the last possible value.