# Cause an ASP.NET RangeValidator to fire when the value of the ControlToValidate is updated via jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, validation

I have a set of date range controls:

```
<div id="CustomDateRow" class="row-fluid" runat="server">
    <label class="span2 FieldLabel">
        Start Date:
    </label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="StartDate" CssClass="datepicker span3" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    <label class="span2 FieldLabel">
        End Date:
    </label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="EndDate" CssClass="datepicker span3" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

I'm converting those controls to jQuery UI date pickers.

I need to ensure that the user can't select more than 30 days at any given time. Originally I had planned on setting the `maxDate` of the `EndDate` when the `StartDate` is set, but there are two basic problems with that.

1. There's no good `DateTime.AddMonths()` analogous function in JavaScript.
2. This [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419804/restrict-date-in-jquery-datepicker-based-on-another-datepicker-or-textbox/4419824#comment18444599_4419824) made me realize that it's really much less user friendly.

So, I figured I'll just use a `RangeValidator` and validate the number of days between the two dates every time the values change.

So, I have a `RangeValidator` like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <asp:RangeValidator ID="DateRangeValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DateRange"
        ErrorMessage="The date range must be at least one day and not more than thirty."
        EnableClientScript="true" MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="30" CssClass="errortext span9 offset2"
        Display="Dynamic" />
</div>
```

And it's validating a basic text input control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DateRange" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Which is updated in JavaScript when the dates change:

```
$('.datepicker').change(function () {
    var nDifference = Math.abs(new Date($('#StartDate').val()) - new Date($('#EndDate').val()));
    var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    $('#DateRange').val(Math.round(nDifference / one_day));
});
```

### The Problem

Even though the value does change when I set it via jQuery, the `RangeValidator` doesn't react. However, if I type the value into the text input and leave it the `RangeValidator` works as expected.

***Do I need to fire some kind of event on the `DateRange` control to force the `RangeValidator` to execute?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ended up doing two pretty simple things to solve this and it all resided in the JavaScript method to calculate the range. Here is the working code.

```
$('.datepicker').change(function () {
    var nDifference = new Date($('#EndDate').val()) - new Date($('#StartDate').val());
    var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    $('#DateRange').val(Math.round(nDifference / one_day));
    Page_ClientValidate(null);
});
```

Note that I got rid of the `Math.abs` on the `nDifference` calculation because I needed the real difference, positive or negative. Finally, note that I added the line `Page_ClientValidate(null);`, that's what causes the `RangeValidator` I setup to validate.

Works perfectly!