# Datepicker ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am new to jquery, How do we make the date to appear in the textbox on the click of an button using jquery and ASP.NET? The calendar apears but it disappears very fast works fine with a textbox? What else do i need to include in the script of my button?
I have used this function

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 $(document).ready(dateselect)
    function dateselect()
     {
      var date1 = $("#Button1").datepicker();
     } 
</script>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  />
```

Comment: Please post your generated/rendered HTML. ASP.NET server tags are useless for debugging client-script issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
        $("#<%= txtFrom.ClientID %>").datepicker({
            showmonth:true,
            autoSize: true,
            showAnim: 'slideDown',
            duration: 'fast'
        });

        $("#<%= ImageButton1.ClientID %>").click(function() {
          $("#<%= txtFrom.ClientID %>").datepicker('show');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Code:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" MaxLength="10" runat="server" ToolTip="Enter From Date">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/clock_add.gif" />
```

Reference [jquery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/displaying-a-datepicker-on-custom-button-click-event)

### Edit 1

Change this function

```
 $("#<%= ImageButton1.ClientID %>").click(function() {
          $("#<%= txtFrom.ClientID %>").datepicker('show');
        });
```

to

```
 $("#<%= ImageButton1.ClientID %>").click(function() {
          $("#<%= txtFrom.ClientID %>").datepicker('show');
          return false;
        });
```

or

```
  $("#<%= ImageButton1.ClientID %>").click(function(event) {
          $("#<%= txtFrom.ClientID %>").datepicker('show');
          event.preventDefault();
        });
```

### Edit 2

```
$("#txtStartDate").datepicker({
  showOn: "both",       
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
     $("#txtEndDate").datepicker("option","minDate",
     $("#txtStartDate").datepicker("getDate"));
  }
});
```

Source :
[Restrict date in jquery datepicker based on another datepicker or textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419804/restrict-date-in-jquery-datepicker-based-on-another-datepicker-or-textbox)

Comment: Thank you very much Shekhar, but the issue is as soon as i click on the image button the datepicker appears and suddenly disppears without even letting the date to be selected.

Comment: The problem is very simple I am editing my answer please see it. You need to use `return false`.

Comment: Thank you Shekhar for your generosity. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. And don't forgot to mark it if it helped you.

Comment: I have marked it and i again need to consult you what if i need two image buttons and two textboxes and in the first textbox the starting date goes and in the second textbox only the date after the date in textbox1 goes?

Comment: @user2210256 Kindly put a new question for that.

Comment: @user2210256 I have update my answer if it work then fine otherwise post a new question for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#txtDate").datepicker({
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonText: 'Show Date',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif'
    });
});
</script>
<input type='text' id='txtDate' />
```

It works fine i had tried this

Comment: @gdoron sorry i can not see the link now it had been removed anyways i just wanted to say what was the need to edit a spam answer