# How to restrict datepicker end date based on start date in jquery-ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Im trying to get the the user who chooses a start date in #ftm-field1, and when a date in #ftm-field1 is chosen, **the user cannot choose an end date that is before #ftm-field1**. The end date is chosen in #ftm-field2.

```
var dateToday = new Date();
$('#formTaskManagement #ftm-field1').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: null,
    maxDate: dateToday,
});

$('#formTaskManagement #ftm-field2').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: null,
    maxDate: dateToday,
});
```

I've tried using

```
$('#formTaskManagement #ftm-field1').datepicker({
        minDate: null,
        maxDate: dateToday,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
            $('#formTaskManagement #ftm-field2').datepicker({minDate: selected})
        }
    });

    $('#formTaskManagement #ftm-field2').datepicker({
        minDate: null,
        maxDate: dateToday,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
            $('#formTaskManagement #ftm-field1').datepicker({maxDate: selected})
        }
    });
```

I've tried this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419804/restrict-date-in-jquery-datepicker-based-on-another-datepicker-or-textbox) as well but have not been successful.

It just simply doesn't work. Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery UI date Picker [`minDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) value should have been a string not a completed date OR minDate also accepts a date object . But in your case you are trying  to set mindate using a `date string`not as a date object.

Try to set min-date using following way:

```
$('#DatePicker').datepicker("option", "minDate", new Date(dateText));
```

Try this code maybe it would helps you to achive your goal-

```
var dateToday = new Date();
$('#txtDate1').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: null,
    maxDate: dateToday,
     onSelect: function(selected) {
        $('#txtDate2').datepicker("option", "minDate",  $("#txtDate1").datepicker('getDate') )
     }
});

$('#txtDate2').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: null,
    maxDate: dateToday,
});
```

[Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4VM5/15/)

Answer (score 0):

try onClose instead.

```
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( "#formTaskManagement #ftm-field1" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );

onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( "#formTaskManagement #ftm-field2" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
```

and to do today's date as maxdate => `maxDate: '0'`