# Select date range based upon previous date

Tags: php, jquery, date, datetime

I'm having 2 textbox for date. One is `From Date` & another is `To Date`.

Let us say.

> From Date 1
>
> To Date 1

&

> From Date 2
>
> To Date 2

I am using date picker for textboxes. If user select 24-01-2012 in 'From Date 1' & 24-01-2016 in 'To Date 1'. Then, I've to restrict user to select date in 'From Date 2' from 01-01-1935 -To- date selected in 'From Date 1'.

```
<?
$current_year = date("Y");
$past_year = $current_year - 80;
?>
```

I'm storing date as

```
var FromDate1= $("#FromDate1").val(); 
var ToDate1= $("#ToDate1").val(); 

var FromDate2= $("#FromDate2").val(); 
var ToDate2= $("#ToDate2").val();
```

Here, `$past_year` and `$current_year` is available. How can I restrict user to select date in 'From Date 2' from `01-01-1935` -To- `'FromDate1'`.

```
$(".addmorefromP").datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: new Date(),
    changeMonth: true,
    yearRange: '<?php echo $past_year . ':' . $current_year; ?>',
    dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
    onClose: function () {
      $(this).valid();
    }
});
```

Here, `yearRange: '<?php echo $past_year . ':' . $current_year; ?>',` is used. Is there any way to use `FromDate1` in place of `$current_year`.

I have been trying since 2 hours. I am not good in jquery, so i was unable to do it. Any help/hint is appreciable. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict date in jquery datepicker based on another datepicker or textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419804/restrict-date-in-jquery-datepicker-based-on-another-datepicker-or-textbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at below code. May be it will be helpful.

Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/pqhtt7gb/5/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="date1">
     FromDate1: <input id="FromDate1" data-index="0" class="datepickerStart" type="text" />
     ToDate1: <input id="ToDate1" data-index="0" class="datepickerEnd" type="text" />
</div> 

<div id="date2">
     FromDate2: <input id="FromDate2" data-index="1" class="datepickerStart" type="text" />
     ToDate2: <input id="ToDate2" data-index="1" class="datepickerEnd" type="text" />
</div>
```

**JQuery Code:**

```
$(".datepickerStart").datepicker({
    constrainInput: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function (selectedDate, obj) {
        var index = obj.input.data("index");
        $(".datepickerEnd[data-index="+index+"]").datepicker("option", "minDate", new Date(selectedDate));
        if(index == 0){
            $(".datepickerStart[data-index=1],.datepickerEnd[data-index=1]").datepicker("option", "maxDate", new Date(selectedDate));

        }
    }
});

var currentDate = new Date();
var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
var pastYear = currentYear - 80;
var pastDate = new Date(pastYear+"/01/01");

$(".datepickerStart[data-index=1]").datepicker("option", "minDate", pastDate);

$(".datepickerStart[data-index=1]").datepicker( "setDate", pastDate);

$(".datepickerEnd").datepicker({
    constrainInput: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    numberOfMonths: 1
});
```

Comment: Gud One Vijay. Thanks. :)

Comment: Welcome @NanaPartykar - Your profile description is awesome...`:)`!

Comment: ThankYou @VijayDeenanathChauhan. :) (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".addmorefromP").datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: new Date(),
        changeMonth: true,
        minDate:new Date(<?php echo $past_year;?>),
        maxDate:new Date(<?php echo $current_year;?>),
        //yearRange: '<?php echo $past_year . ':' . $current_year; ?>',
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
        onClose: function () {
          $(this).valid();
        }
    });
```