# Restricted dates on two datepickers jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I have a problem I can't seem to fint the answer to, even after 10 hours or so of Googling.. SO, dear friends;

I have two datepickers which works perfectly together, but the last thing I need is restricted date range in the last datepicker. The restricted date in should be 14 days from the date you've picked in the first datepicker. I've tried maxDate, but it only restricts the date from today and 14 days in the future, but what I want is to limit it from the chosen first date and then 14 days in the future after that date. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="when" class="input-date" id="calendarfrom"/>
<input type="text" name="when" class="input-date" id="calendarto"/>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#calendarfrom").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        minDate: 0,
        monthNames: ["Januar", "Februar", "Mars", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Desember"],
        dayNamesMin: ['Søn', 'Man', 'Tir', 'Ons', 'Tor', 'Fre', 'Lør'],
        firstDay: 1,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#calendarto").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#calendarto").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        monthNames: ["Januar", "Februar", "Mars", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Desember"],
        dayNamesMin: ['Søn', 'Man', 'Tir', 'Ons', 'Tor', 'Fre', 'Lør'],
        firstDay: 1,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#calendarfrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the date you need to add days to the selected date and then use the `maxDate`.

`onClose` for from datepicker :

**JSFIDDLE** : https://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/a9a6jjkv/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#calendarfrom").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        minDate: 0,
        monthNames: ["Januar", "Februar", "Mars", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Desember"],
        dayNamesMin: ['Søn', 'Man', 'Tir', 'Ons', 'Tor', 'Fre', 'Lør'],
        firstDay: 1,
        onClose: function (date) {
            var dateParts = date.split("/");
            var dateObject = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[0]);
            var selectedDate = new Date(dateObject);
            var numberOfDaysToAdd = 14;
            var endDate = new Date(selectedDate);
            endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
            $("#calendarto").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            $("#calendarto").datepicker("option", "maxDate", endDate);
        }
    });
    $("#calendarto").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        monthNames: ["Januar", "Februar", "Mars", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Desember"],
        dayNamesMin: ['Søn', 'Man', 'Tir', 'Ons', 'Tor', 'Fre', 'Lør'],
        firstDay: 1,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#calendarfrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

You can check the more description at : 
[Restrict date in jquery datepicker based on another datepicker or textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419804/restrict-date-in-jquery-datepicker-based-on-another-datepicker-or-textbox)

Comment: This is not working.. I'm not sure where to put this code. Are you suggestesting I put it on the onClose for the #calendarfrom tag? Or both?

Comment: Yes its for the calendarfrom datepicker. Let me update my answer.

Comment: It's still not working.. It's only showing 14 days from todays date, but what I need is 14 days from the selected date in the first input. So if I choose November 1st, it should show a range up to November 15th, but as of right now it only shows November 10th (which is 14 days from today)

Comment: @TaniaHol, I have update my answer and also added on Fiddle for it. Issue was date format. It should be working now.