# Bootstrap datepicker set max and min based on other date input

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to restrict the date so datepicker1 can not be greater than datepicker2 and datepicker2 can not be less than datepicker1. I started with: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ (Linked Pickers). This did not restrict date input. So then I found [Restrict date in jquery datepicker based on another datepicker or textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419804/restrict-date-in-jquery-datepicker-based-on-another-datepicker-or-textbox) However, none of these answers restricted the date input.

The best I can guess is that I have a missing library/src.

My jQuery is (you can see all the examples I have tried, some did not reformat the date):

```
$(function(){
    $("#includedContent").load("Menu.html");

//    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
//        showOn: "both",
//        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
//        onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
//           $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option","minDate",
//           $("#datepicker1").datepicker("getDate"));
//        }
//      });
//    
//    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
//        showOn: "both",
//        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
//        onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
//           $("#datepicker1").datepicker("option","maxDate",
//           $("#datepicker2").datepicker("getDate"));
//        }
//      });

//    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
//        showOn: "both",
//        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', //date formated correctly
//        maxDate: $("#datepicker2").datepicker("getDate")
//    });
//    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
//        showOn: "both",
//        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', //Does not format the address it is returned as mm/dd/yyyy
//        minDate: $("#datepicker1").datepicker("getDate")
//    });


    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy', //Does not format the address it is returned as mm/dd/yyyy
        inline: true,
         maxDate: $("#datepicker2").datepicker("getDate") });
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy', //Does not format the address it is returned as mm/dd/yyyy
        inline: true,
         minDate: $("#datepicker1").datepicker("getDate") });


//    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
//      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
//          });
//    $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
//      useCurrent: false, //Important! See issue #1075
//      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
//    });
//    $("#datepicker1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
//        $('#datepicker2').data("DatePicker").minDate(e.date);
//    });
//    $("#datepicker2").on("dp.change", function (e) {
//        $('#datepicker1').data("DatePicker").maxDate(e.date);
//    });
});



$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
}); // end document.ready
```

The HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cub Award Overview</title>
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="A Scout award tracking application">
    <meta name="author" content="Glyndwr (Wirrin) Bartlett">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="cubAwards"  class="container-fluid" style="background-repeat: repeat; background-image: url('images/body-bg.jpg');">

        <div id="includedContent"></div>

        <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="showYMAwards">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                        <h3>Group Summary</h3>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' id='exportDetails'>Export Details</button>

                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class='input-group date' id='datepicker1'>
                                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class='input-group date' id='datepicker2'>
                                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- Place for Awards -->
                        <div class="input-select" id="img-container1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <span id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse" style="color: red;"></span>
    </div>

    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="resources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>

    <script src="js/groupSummary-ajax.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this and maybe this could be helpful to you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
        $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
        });
        $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is where I started ( https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). Please see the last commented out code. I have amended it to use datepicker instead of datetimepicker (I do not want the time shown) the rest is the same.