# Set a datepicker maxDate from another datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

In my app I have a form with 3 datepicker objects; `from`, `to`, and `apply_to`.  I tried in JavaScript to set the control input `to` and `apply_to`

```
 $("#from").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    onSelect: function(selected) {
        $("#to").datepicker("option","minDate", selected);

        $("#apply_to").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)

    }
});
```

But I need to set `maxDate` in `apply_to` to the selected date minus one.

```
$("#apply_to").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected-1d)
```

But my code is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict date in jquery datepicker based on another datepicker or textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419804/restrict-date-in-jquery-datepicker-based-on-another-datepicker-or-textbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onSelect, the `selected` parameter is a string so you must first convert it to a javascript date object, then subtract one day using setDate / getDate, and finally update the corresponding datepicker maxDate option

```
onSelect: (selected) => {
        var pieces = selected.split('.');
        var dt = new Date(pieces[2], parseInt(pieces[1])-1, pieces[0]);
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
        $("#to" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate",  dt);
  }
```